# files in docker image always owned by root

Tags: docker, yarnpkg

My docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:focal as influencer-scraper

USER root

# Install tools as telnet
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install telnet -y
# RUN apk add chromium

RUN groupadd --gid 888 node \
    && useradd --uid 888 --gid node --shell /bin/bash --create-home node

USER node
WORKDIR /home/node
# Copy package.json and Yarn install (separate for cache)
COPY ./package.json ./
COPY ./yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn
# Copy everything and build
COPY . .
# Copy other config files
COPY ./.env ./.env

# Entry point
ENTRYPOINT ["yarn", "start"]
CMD ["--mongodb", "host.docker.internal:27017"]
```

However, after I login to the docker image, I found that all files are owned by root, which is creating trouble during the runtime

```
➜  influencer-scraper-js git:(master) ✗ docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash influencer-scraper:v0.1-6-gfe17ad4962-dirty
node@bce54c1024db:~$ ls -l
total 52
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   542 Apr 16 04:15 Docker.md
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   589 Apr 16 05:03 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   570 Apr 16 03:58 Makefile
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   358 Apr 13 01:27 README.md
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root    20 Apr 16 03:58 config
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root    16 Apr 16 03:58 data
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root    14 Apr 12 06:00 docker
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   558 Apr 16 03:58 docker-compose.yml
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   140 Apr 13 01:27 generated
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  1676 Apr 16 04:47 node_modules
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   583 Apr 16 03:58 package.json
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root    34 Apr 13 01:27 proxy
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root    40 Apr 13 01:27 src
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 26230 Apr 16 03:58 yarn.lock
```

How can I resolve this? I would like the workdir to be still owned by user `node`.

Answer (score 2):

The file listing you show looks almost correct to me.  You *want* most of the files to be owned by `root` and not be world-writeable: in the event that there's some security issue or other bug in your code, you don't want that to accidentally overwrite your source files, static assets, or other content.

This means you need the actual writeable data to be stored in a different directory, and your listing includes a `data` directory which presumably serves this role.  You can `chown` it in your Dockerfile.

For clarity, it helps to stay as the root user until the very end of the file, and then you can declare the alternate user to actually run the container.

```sh
# USER root (if required)
RUN chown node data
...
USER node
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

When you launch the container, you can mount a volume on that specific directory.  This setup should work as-is with a named volume

```
docker run \
  -v app_data:/home/node/data \
  ...
```

If you want/need to use a host directory to store the data, you also need to specify the host user ID that owns the directory (typically the current user).  Again, the application code will be owned by `root` and world-readable, so this won't change; it's only the `data` directory whose contents and ownership matter.

```
docker run \
  -u $(id -u) \
  -v "$(pwd)/app_data:/home/node/data" \
  ...
```

(Do not use volumes to replace the application code or libraries in the container.  In this particular case, doing that would obscure this configuration problem in the Dockerfile, and your container setup would fail when you tried to deploy to production without the local-build volumes.)

Answer (score 0):

Quoting Docker Documentation : https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy

> COPY has two forms:
>
> ```
> COPY [--chown=<user>:<group>] <src>... <dest>
> COPY [--chown=<user>:<group>] ["<src>",... "<dest>"]
> ```

If you do not specify any user in `--chown`, the default used is `root`

> All new files and directories are created with a UID and GID of 0, unless the optional --chown flag specifies a given username, groupname, or UID/GID combination to request specific ownership of the copied content.

---

You can also try doing `chown` after copying.

```
chown root:node filename
```